# React PrivateRoute not rendering children properly

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4

[Link to sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/broken-worker-9xmm7?file=/src/history.js)
When I am using `PrivateRoute`, the DOM is rendering `<children history="[object Object]" location="[object Object]" match="[object Object]"></children>` instead of the `<AdminLayout/>` which I am passing in `AppRouter`.

Not sure where I am going wrong. [image: screenshot of dom]

**ERROR from `PrivateRoute`: children undefined**

and this:

*`Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports`.*

```
Check the render method of `Context.Consumer`.
```

This is `PrivateRoute`

```
import React from "react";
import { Route, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";

function PrivateRoute({ children, roles, ...rest }) {
  console.log("childen", children);
  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={(props) => {
        console.log("propsssss", props);
        // if (!localStorage.getItem('userid')) {
        if (!localStorage.getItem("access_token")) {
          // not logged in so redirect to login page with the return url
          return (
            <Redirect
              to={{ pathname: "/auth/login", state: { from: props.location } }}
            />
          );
        }

        // logged in so return component
        return <children {...props}/>;
      }}
    />
  );
}

export default PrivateRoute;
```

And this is `AppRouter`

```
import React from "react";
import { Router, Route, Switch, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";

import history from "../helpers/history";

import AdminLayout from "layouts/Admin/Admin.js";
import AuthLayout from "layouts/Auth/Auth.js";
import PrivateRoute from "./PrivateRoute";

const AppRouter = () => {
  return (
    <Router history={history}>
        <PrivateRoute path="/admin" render={(props) => <AdminLayout {...props} />} />
        <Route
          path="/auth/login"
          render={(props) => <AuthLayout {...props} />}
        />
        <Redirect from="*" to="/auth/login" />
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
};

export default AppRouter;
```

and this is `history.js`

```
import { createBrowserHistory } from "history";

const history = createBrowserHistory();

export default history;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems in code one is you are using `renderProps` for generating component but in your `PrivateRoute` component you are expecting as a children. Correct way of doing this:

```
<PrivateRoute path="/admin">
   <AdminLayout />
</PrivateRoute>
```

and inside `PrivateRoute` you need to return children as it is:

```
function PrivateRoute({ children, roles, ...rest }) {
  console.log("childen", children);
  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={(props) => {
        console.log("propsssss", props);
        // if (!localStorage.getItem('userid')) {
        if (!localStorage.getItem("access_token")) {
          // not logged in so redirect to login page with the return url
          return (
            <Redirect
              to={{ pathname: "/auth/login", state: { from: props.location } }}
            />
          );
        }

        // logged in so return component
        return children;
      }}
    />
  );
}
```

Comment: Its hard to say anything then. can you add your code to codesandbox?

Comment: @got an error: `childen undefined` from PrivateRoute

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/broken-worker-9xmm7?file=/src/history.js

Comment: There are couple issues in code . You don't set `localstorage`, using `Router` instead of `BrowserHistory`. Updated code: https://codesandbox.io/s/hardcore-glitter-xzrk8?file=/src/AppRouter.js

Comment: thanks. Updated sandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-mirzakhani-8s0sz?file=/src/Sidebar.js:320-327 Getting `TypeError: Cannot read property 'pathname' of undefined` error `SideBar.js` I have added the code and shared the updated sandbox.

Comment: You are using class state in functional component

Comment: Login and admin are functional. sidebar is a class component

Comment: Inside Admin component you are using `this.state` where is your `Admin` component is functional component

Comment: updated `Admin.js` https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-mirzakhani-8s0sz?file=/src/AdminNavbar.js

Comment: Where is your `routes.js` is importing. I see it is commented there

Comment: that one has routes for the sidebar only. thats why not included it

Comment: How will `getActiveRoute` know what is route value then?

Comment: the error is from Sidebar.js not from Admin.js. Look for `activeRoute()` at Line no: 125 in Sidebar.js

Comment: I am seeing error in Admin.js : https://imgur.com/a/RVGsRXq

Comment: just comment out that line. AppRouter is the real deal. `routes` is only contains routing for sidebar since its a SPA.